# Bytes in area between two hex memory addresses

Tags: assembly, zos

I am currently reading a book about Mainframe Assembly (Assembly Language Programming for System Z)

In one of the first chapters I got stuck on the following question:

> 3.1.1.(2)+ An area of memory reserved for data begins at address X'2EC9' and ends with address X'30A6' (including the start and end
> bytes!). How many bytes are there in the area, and how many halfwords,
> words, and doublewords can be stored in the area?

I understand what they mean but I am not sure on how to think to find out the number of bytes between these Hexadecimal addresses.

Comment: How many numbers are there between 123 and 456 (inclusive?).  Hex instead of decimal is just a different way of writing numbers.

Comment: So we have 333 numbers in between them, and each address holds 1 byte? Which means 333 bytes in between them?

Comment: Note that the calculator in Windows has a "Programmer" mode where you can write and view numbers in 4 different bases. There are probably applications with similar functionality for other OS:s in case you're not on Windows.

Comment: how many numbers are there between 1 and 5?   5-1 or 5-1+1 or other?

Answer (score 4):

Computer memory is counted in bytes, which (usually) are numbered from zero upwards. You can count in decimal or, which is more usual, in hexadecimal. Processor instruction operate on single bytes, and on a number of bytes. The number of bytes may be a fixed number, or a varying number.

The terms *Halfword*, *Fullword*, *Doubleword*, *Quadword* are terms for fixed number of byte units, and depend on the definition of the term *word*. A *Word* of bytes may comprise 2, 4, or 8 succeeding bytes of memory.

In the **IBM z/Architecture**, (and its predecessors back to IBM S/360) a *word* consists of 4 bytes. A *Fullword" ("FW" in the figure below) is the same as a "Word". A *Halfword* ("HW" below) is half a word, so it's 2 bytes. A *Doubleword* ("DW") is 2 words, so it's 8 bytes. Finally, a *Quadword* is 4 words, so it's 16 bytes.

Note that some processor instructions require the operands to lie on a halfword, fullword, doubleword, or even quadword boundary. That means the address, or the number, of the lowest numbered byte must divisible by 2, 4, 8, or 16, resp.. This coined the terms *halfword aligned", "fullword aligned", etc.

Other instructions operate on halfword, fullword, etc., operands no matter wether they are aligned or not. So, in general the terms denote a specific number of succeding bytes of memory.

The figure below illustrates those terms :

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---
| B | B | B | B | B | B | B | B | B | B | B | B | B | B | B | B | B | B |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---
00  01  02  03  04  05  06  07  08  09  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18   decimal
00  01  02  03  04  05  06  07  08  09  0A  0B  0C  0D  0E  0F  10  11  12   hexadecimal

+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+---
|   HW  |   HW  |   HW  |   HW  |   HW  |   HW  |   HW  |   HW  |   HW  |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+---
00      02      04      06      08      10      12      14      16      18   decimal
00      02      04      06      08      0A      0C      0E      10      12   hexadecimal

+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+-----------
|       FW      |       FW      |       FW      |       FW      |       FW
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+-----------
00              04              08              12              16           decimal
00              04              08              0C              10           hexadecimal

+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-----------
|               DW              |               DW              |        DW
+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-----------
00                              08                              16           decimal
00                              08                              10           hexadecimal

+---------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
|                               QW                              |        QW
+---------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
00                                                              16           decimal
00                                                              10           hexadecimal
```

B  = Byte, HW = Halfword, FW = Fullword, DW = Doubleword, QW = Quadword

Finally, back to your question. The first byte is byte number 2EC9 (in hex notation), and the last is byte number 30A6. The difference between the two numbers plus 1 equals the number of bytes. 30A6 - 2EC9 + 1 = 1DE (in hex), or 478 (in decimal).

If we ignore alignment, there are 478 / 2 = 239 halfwords, 478 / 4 = 119 fullwords (and 2 bytes left), 478 / 8 = 59 doublewords (and 6 bytes left), and 478 / 16 = 29 quadwords (and 14 bytes left).

On the other hand, if we adhere to alignment, firstly, we need to find the next halfword, fullword, doubleword, and, quadword boundary starting at 2EC9. This is 2ECA, 2ECC, 2ED0, and 2ED0, resp.. Secondly, we need to find the last address where a HW, FW, DW, or QW may start, having the last byte still below or equal to address 30A6. This is 30A4, 30A0, 3098, and 3090, resp..

The result is 238 halfwords (and 2 bytes left), 118 fullwords (and 6 bytes left), 58 doublewords (and 14 bytes left), and finally, 29 quadwords (and 14 bytes left).

Since you are learning assembler programming, you better learn hexadecimal arithmetic.

Comment: There is a typo in your reply, the Quadword is 16 bytes not 8.

Comment: If you consider alignment (half, full, double, ...) then there are 238 possible half words, 119 fullwords, 59 doublewords.  this is because the first byte is not on a word aligned boundary (2EC9).

Comment: @Hogstrom Thanks for reminding me, this time, of being lazy :-) I have adjusted my answer, and hopefully all calculations are correct.

Comment: @phunsoft laziness is a human trait.  Diligence is a team sport.  In this together .